# Unit testing and minimizing "Arrange" phase with central DI logic

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mstest

The only problem I have with my unit tests is that my `Arrange` phases (in `Arrange-Act-Assert pattern`) are quite long so that maintainability problems arise. I have dozens of registrations which I make in constructor of test classes. Some of the test classes have common registrations and I thought that I can move all of these registrations in one central place and use `AssemblyInitialize` attribute on it (e.g. this approach will be like the registration part in `Global.asax` or `Startup.cs`). And if one wants to override the registered type, it can simply re-registers it (my container overrides the old registered type in that case). However, there will be some extra registrations made for some test classes too.

Would that be a bad decision? And if so, why?

Are there any third party tools that can help me with that (maybe in a better way)?

Would my unit test timings take a great hit by doing this? Because some of the test classes have only a few registrations. Should I use something to ignore these central registrations for them maybe?

**Edit:**

Sample Code:

```
private CustomersController controller;

public CustomersControllerTests()
{
    var container = ContainerFactory.GetContainer();
    MapperConfiguration autoMapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<DefaultMappingProfile>();
    });
    container.RegisterInstance(autoMapperConfig);
    container.Register<Common.Contracts.Mapper.IMapper, AutoMapperWrapped>(Lifetime.Singleton);
    container.Register<IProxy, BusinessProxy>();
    container.Register<IDataContext, FakeDataContext>();
    container.Register<IUnitOfWork, FakeUnitOfWork>();
    container.Register<ICustomerBusiness, CustomerBusiness>();
    //...Some more registrations
    controller = new CustomersController();
} 

[TestMethod]
public async Task GetCustomerById_ForNonExistingCustomer_ReturnsNotFound()
{
    //Act
    var result = await controller.GetCustomerById(0);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(NotFoundResult));
}
```

For this test method, the Arrange part is in the constructor of the test class as shown.

Comment: Some code examples would be nice. Have you considered mocking these classes?

Comment: It sounds like you have too many dependencies and are trying to solve too many problems in a limited number of methods. Could you show some code please?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this sounds like what I do as well. I setup my IoC container and then override registrations with mocked ones for the items that will actually be called in that test. In one particular build I have over 260 unit tests and they all complete on the build server in less than 5 seconds. [I also have a blog post](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/11/05/organizing-service-mocks-in-unit-tests/) that does not use IoC, but does offer guidance on organizing mocks.

Comment: @Sam I added a sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unit testing is testing the single unit - ie class.  Any dependencies should ideally be mocks where you are fully in control of what is returned from them.

A good pattern to follow, though some disagree, is the SUT Builder pattern.  This is explained brilliantly in the Advanced Unit Testing Course by Mark Seemann on Pluralsight - anyone wanting to unit test - I try and point them at this course.

[Advanced Unit Testing](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/advanced-unit-testing)

The SUT Builder pattern is a Fluent API you basically use to create your System Under Test (SUT) - ie, the class being unit tested.  This promotes readability of your tests and keeps things DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

**Quick Example**

```
internal sealed class MySutBuilder
{
    private ISignInService _webServiceSignInService;


    public MySutBuilder()
    {
        _webServiceSignInService = new Mock<ISignInService>().Object;
    }

    public MySutBuilder WithSecurityAccess()
    {
        var authenticationMock = new Mock<ISignInService>();
        authenticationMock.Setup(m => m.SignIn(It.IsAny<GetDocumentContentRequest>()))
                    .Returns(SignInResult.Success(new ServiceUserContextMock()));

           _webServiceSignInService = authenticationMock.Object;

        return this;
    }

    public MyService Build()
    {
        MyService cut = new MyService(_webServiceSignInService);

        return cut;
    }
}
```

So the idea is using the SutBuilder in your unit test to control dependencies for that class.  If you add things to the constructor, then you only need to fix this in the one place in the test - but I guess this would depend on how your tests roll.

This is a cut down piece of code, so the classes we have can get quite large with 5+ dependencies per class.

**Unit Test Usage**

```
// arrange
var sut = new MySutBuilder()
    .WithSecrityAccess()
    .Build();

// act
var result = sut.DoSomething();

// assert
```